# (PostgreSQL trigger function) How to use TG_ARGV as column names of NEW and OLD?

Tags: postgresql, trigger, plpgsql

I am trying to create a trigger function in PostgreSQL that will take `TG_ARGV[0]` and `TG_ARGV[1]` and use those as column names of `NEW` and `OLD`, so that I can pass them in as arguments like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER users_hash_image_a
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF "image_a" ON "users"
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE hash_image_trigger("image_a", "image_a_md5");
```

My function is this, but it doesn't work:

```
CREATE FUNCTION hash_image_trigger() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
  $$
  BEGIN
    new.TG_ARGV[1] = MD5(new.TG_ARGV[0]);
    RETURN new;
  END
  $$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

How can I use `TG_ARGV` as column names of `NEW` and `OLD`?

Answer (score 1):

This is a little bit tricky in PL/pgSQL. To get the value from a dynamically-determined column, you can use [`EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN), as so:

```sql
DECLARE
    _md5val text;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('SELECT MD5(($1).%I)', TG_ARGV[0]) USING NEW INTO _md5val;
END;
```

However, to *assign* to a dynamically determined column, cannot so easily be done. For that, I commonly use the [`hstore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html) extension from the `contrib` module.

The `hstore` extension has an `anyelement #= hstore` opeatator, so that you can do something like:

```sql
NEW := NEW #= hstore(TG_ARGV[1], _md5val);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked, without needing `hstore`, but I don't know if it's the "correct" way to do it, or if there's anything unsafe:

```
CREATE FUNCTION hash_image_trigger() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
  $$
  DECLARE
    image bytea := row_to_json(new)->>TG_ARGV[0];
  BEGIN
    new := json_populate_record(new, json_build_object(TG_ARGV[1], MD5(image)));
    RETURN new;
  END
  $$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: json isntead of hstore - it's basically the same mechnism.